# Nested Serializer creates new object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer called EntrySerializer and it should return the staff details but if I want to create a new entry it wants to create a new staff object and throws an error. Is there anything like a read only field for my serializer? It should create a new entry but assign an already created staff object.

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    staff = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_staff')

    def get_staff(self, obj):
        return MyUserSerializer(obj.staff).data

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        depth = 1
        fields = ('time_spend', 'staff',)
```

Error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ERROR:  NULL-value in Column »staff_id« relation »tagesbericht_tagesbericht_Entry« Not-Null-Constraint
DETAIL: (54, 00:00:08.5, null, 61).

POST:

"tagesbericht_entry_set": [
{
"staff": 2,
"time_spend": "00:12:08"
}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the `staff_id` field for writing.

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    staff = MyUserSerializer(read_only = True)
    staff_id = Serializers.IntegerField(write_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        depth = 1
        fields = ('time_spend', 'staff', 'staff_id')
```

And the POST payload should be

```
{
    "staff_id": 2,
    "time_spend": "00:12:08"
}
```